# How to get table columns according its schema and table name?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get `ColumnName` and it's `datatype` and `is_identity` for each column of different databases for specific `table` and `schema`.

I use following code but `SCHEMA_NAME` is for current database but I want to run this query from `master or another database`.

How to check schema name?

```
SELECT  
   c.name AS column_name, tp.name as data_type, c.is_identity iden 
FROM 
   DatabaseName.sys.tables AS t 
INNER JOIN 
   DatabaseName.sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID 
INNER JOIN 
   DatabaseName.sys.types tp ON c.user_type_id =  tp.user_type_id  
WHERE
   t.name = 'PlaceType' 
   AND SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) = 'Coding'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `SCHEMA_NAME`, use `OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME`, like so:

```
SELECT  c.name AS column_name,tp.name as data_type,c.is_identity iden FROM 
DatabaseName.sys.tables AS t INNER JOIN 
DatabaseName.sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID INNER JOIN 
DatabaseName.sys.types tp ON c.user_type_id =  tp.user_type_id  where 
t.name='PlaceType' and OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id,DB_ID(Databasename))='Coding'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the last condition like

```
and SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) in (Select name from Sys.Databases where database_id > 4)
```